# Filter Query Set without list_filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My model look like :

```
class address_fetcher(models.Model):
    county__info = models.ForeignKey(County_Info)
    billable_api_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Billable API', null = True, blank = True)
    is_dryrun = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Dry Run')
......
......


class County_Info(models.Model):
    county = models.ForeignKey(County)
    start = models.IntegerField()
    .....
    .....

class County(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = True)
    key  = models.CharField(max_length = 5, blank = True)

    .....
    .....
    .....
```

I have to filter 'address_fetcher' model by county name ( In the model 'County')
But 'County' table has 20489 recode . So i cant able to use list_filter. because it will load a big data in the filer . Also it slow down the page loading .

My Question is Simple,

How i can filter this without using list_filter ?? 
if i append url without list_filter  '...?county_info__county__name=nameofcounty' throwing an exception. But i add the list_filter then it will not throw the exception .

So any one can help me for this issue ?

I ADDED THE SCREEN PRINT OF THE CHANE VIEW PAGE [image: I ADDED THE SCREEN PRINT OF THE CHANE VIEW PAGE]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Address_Fetcher.objects.filter(county_info__county__name = "yourcountyname")
```

Comment: CHECK THE IMAGE THAT I UPLOADED

Comment: You meant you wanted to filter models on the admin page?

Comment: YES  I hope the list_filter and the other information make scene.

Comment: Why do you want a list_filter? Would a search field using name of county be sufficient?

Comment: No coz i want to search by billable_api_count and county . the issue is , when one 'billable_api_count' set and all has same county .the search will not work . Example county name 'CA' has 20 entry in the table and billable_api_count set only for TWO row . then the result will be only TWO not 20 .

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot understand your english and what you want to do exactly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19573/discussion-between-abhilash-joseph-and-siddharth-sarda)